# how to complete missing data in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

i am using an API to download live stock market data.
this information a lot of the time is incomplete.
e.g;

```
                                 Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close   Volume
Datetime
2022-02-16 15:00:00-05:00  172.872101  173.029999  172.839996  172.910004  172.910004        0
2022-02-16 15:01:00-05:00  172.899994  172.949997  172.779999  172.815002  172.815002   160249
2022-02-16 15:04:00-05:00  173.089996  173.320007  173.030106  173.315002  173.315002   311095
2022-02-16 15:05:00-05:00  173.320007  173.339996  173.164993  173.214996  173.214996   174639
2022-02-16 15:07:00-05:00  173.139999  173.179993  173.089996  173.160004  173.160004   135559
```

as you can tell by the timestamp , it skips a lot of information

my question is :
is there a way to complete that missing data to achieve something like this ?

```
                                 Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close   Volume
Datetime
2022-02-16 15:00:00-05:00  172.872101  173.029999  172.839996  172.910004  172.910004        0
2022-02-16 15:01:00-05:00  172.899994  172.949997  172.779999  172.815002  172.815002   160249
2022-02-16 15:02:00-05:00  172.809998  172.990005  172.809998  172.979996  172.979996   119117
2022-02-16 15:03:00-05:00  172.970001  173.169998  172.964996  173.080093  173.080093   264624
2022-02-16 15:04:00-05:00  173.089996  173.320007  173.030106  173.315002  173.315002   311095
2022-02-16 15:05:00-05:00  173.320007  173.339996  173.164993  173.214996  173.214996   174639
2022-02-16 15:06:00-05:00  173.220001  173.220001  173.080002  173.139999  173.139999   124707
2022-02-16 15:07:00-05:00  173.139999  173.179993  173.089996  173.160004  173.160004   135559
```

Comment: have you tried fill forward?  another idea is to resample from daily to weekly or monthly aggregation.  if you don't like fill forward than use interpolation

Comment: Asfreq might be an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With resample to 1 minute periods then interpolate to fill the NaN values

```
df = df.resample('1T').interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='forward', axis=0)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of ways to do this. Go through the whole blog.
https://towardsdatascience.com/6-different-ways-to-compensate-for-missing-values-data-imputation-with-examples-6022d9ca0779

1. Drop the missing data if you've enough data for training.
2. Add the data using the techniques in the blog.